# Getting false instead of true in ProLog

Tags: prolog, logic

I have a database of product information in a shop, which looks like this: `product(Barcode, ProductName, Category, Refrigerated, VendorName)`.

I am trying to write a (very) basic operation to check whether two products have the same barcode.

My code:

```
sameCode(product(code1,_,_,_,_),product(code2,_,_,_,_)):- code1=code2.
```

Yet while checking it I got:

```
52 ?- sameCode(product(972000456745, matches, 05, false, fire_ltd),product(972000456745, lighter,        05, false, fire_ltd)).
false.
```

So I tried to tell it to return `true` always, by making it a statement without demands:

```
sameCode(product(code1,_,_,_,_),product(code2,_,_,_,_)).
```

Yet I still got `false`. Any ideas why it's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `code1` & `code2` are [atoms](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html#atom), and since you’re not passing in the atoms `code1` & `code2`, it doesn’t match and returns `false`. You want [variables](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html#variable) (which begin with a capital letter or underscore) instead:

```
sameCode(product(Code1,_,_,_,_), product(Code2,_,_,_,_)) :- Code1 = Code2.
```

This can be simplified to just:

```
sameCode(product(Code,_,_,_,_), product(Code,_,_,_,_)).
```

as `Code` is, of course, unified with itself.